# '... this good of a wave...'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage

I've just been listening to Jeff Clark, the first to surf Mavericks.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-31093276

Around 2:20 he relates a story with Mark Foo, a Hawaiian surfer:

> The [big wave riders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_wave_surfing), they didn't believe that a wave like this existed. December 1994, I hear that Mark Foo and some of the premier big wave riders from Hawaii were coming to Mavericks. Mark was catching waves, and I'd paddle up to Mark and say, 'Mark, what do you think?' He goes, 'I never imagined it was this good of a wave'.

I translate this (very US-sounding) construction as, 'I never imagined the waves here were so good'.

How does this work, please? Can someone be 'so good of a surfer' for example ?

Comment: "I never imagined it was such a good wave."

Comment: 'this good of'... is a colloquial form for a more grammatical ' such a good'..https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=this+good+of+a

Comment: I've realised that this form may have it's origins in the English of the Mayflower.  Can anyone say ?

Comment: Where did you realise that from?

Comment: @Josh61 I am living with my question and thinking around it, looking for answers from my own experience and knowledge as well as being interested to hear what the experience of this site can suggest.  My 'realisation' came from pondering over the 'retro' sound of this structure to my British ears.  No British English speaker uses this form and yet Jeff Clark is clearly using it comfortably, without affectation.  There are many US turns of phrase that have persisted from Mayflower days that are no longer current in Britain.  Perhaps, I wonder, this is one of them.

Comment: That's interesting..probably you need to modify your question or make a new one if you want to an answer on this issue.

Comment: As a native British English speaker from NW England, it sounds perfectly natural to me. I'm pretty sure that construct and variations of it are used regularly hereabouts.

Comment: @Dan *There are many US turns of phrase that have persisted from Mayflower days*. Do you know of any instances of Shakespeare using it? Or is it in the KJV bible? In my view it is dreadful English and if my children had ever used it I would have stopped their pocket money for a week! (I speak in jest, I am a softie)

Comment: @Dan That is not to say that there are not instances, e.g. after *much*, when the *of* is justified. In the one quoted I would say *How big a wave was it* - no *of* required. But one might say *How much of a statesman was Jefferson*?  or *How many of you are coming*. But definitely not *How pretty of a girl is she*? nor *How big of a wave is it*.

Comment: I'm surprised how unclear my question seems to be.  I am used to asking *How big was the wave?* and answering *The wave was this big*.  My question is that, I think, in the US, it is pretty common (I have heard the usage many times before) to ask *How big OF a wave was it?* and to answer *It was this big OF a wave*.  I don't understand why the 'of' is there (Question 1) and I wonder whether this word pattern  can be traced back to the time of the Mayflower (question 2).

Answer (score 2):

Phrases of the form "this good of a Y" or "that good of a Y" are fairly new to published writing in the United States—to judge from the results of a Google books search for "this good of a," "that good of a," "this big of a," and "that big of a" for the period 1700–2008. The first matches that the search turns up for "this/that good of a" are from 1990, both in the context of sports. From Dave Sloan, [*Sporting News Baseball Guide*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1DK74kE-hDcC&q=%22this+good+of+a%22&dq=%22this+good+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a6HZVJS8IJSNoQTjgoD4Cg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1990) [snippet]:

> And though he had only 45 runs batted in, Browne did an exceptional job of getting runners home from third base with less than two out. "If Jerry is **this good of a** hitter at age 23," Edwards said, "he's going to be one of the best by the time he's 25."

and from Cameron Stauth, [*The Franchise: Building a Winner With the Wold Champion Detroit Pistons, Basketball's Bad Boys*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JQ_L21gYS_MC&q=%22day,+John+Salley,+still%22&dq=%22day,+John+Salley,+still%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zaDZVNCVIMuyoQTM_4KQCQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1990) [combined snippets]:

> Finally having **this good of a** team was something worth celebrating. But maybe in two years Hank Gathers would be of some small value. When you ran the franchise, you had to think like that.

The expression "this [or *that*] big of a" made its debut much earlier, though not in the *Mayflower* era and not in North America. From Gerald Griffin, "[Adventures of an Irish Giant](https://books.google.com/books?id=Si5JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA37&dq=%22that+big+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BqLZVMnkFo_XoATE3YCQDg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22that%20big%20of%20a%22&f=false)," in *Duffy's Fireside Magazine* (Dublin, Ireland, December 1850):

> "Qui't ma'am?" exclaimed the nurse, after having replied to all the fiscal interrogatories— the darlin' o' the world! **that big of a** squall you wouldn't hear outside her lips from one end o' the week to th' other. I never seen a betther crathur, God bless her!"

It next appears in Ruth Stuart, "[Bud Zunts's Mail](https://books.google.com/books?id=DGU-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22that+big+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BqLZVMnkFo_XoATE3YCQDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22that%20big%20of%20a%22&f=false)," in *Harper's New Monthly Magazine* (New York, December 1893):

> "Ef you want to know my thoughts about it, Miss C'delia, I reck'n God A'-mighty put it there. He knew thet it was about time I was gitt'n' a love letter—ef ever I'm goin' to git one—an' He knew there wasn't but one person I'd keer to git it from, an' He knew thet you was that special partic'lar person, an' he knew mo'n that—He knew thet I was such a chicken-hearted ejiot thet less'n some sign come fo' me to speak, I'd 've come an' gone out 0' this Simpkinsville pos'-office eternal 'thout openin' my head to you-I'm jest **that big of a** dummy."

But the key to understanding how "this/that X of a" caught on in the United States, I believe, is to look at the allied expression "this/that much of a." It first appears in Google Books search results from the United States in 1879, in an interesting form. From G.W. Waters, M.D., of Collinsburg, Louisiana, "[Treatment of Pneumonia](https://books.google.com/books?id=hORXAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA146&dq=%22not+that+much+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JanZVPkTyaqhBK2KgLgN&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22not%20that%20much%20of%20a%22&f=false)," in *The Medical Brief* (1879):

> I would not have it understood that aconite is a hobby of mine. I am not **that much of a** "Ringer," but I do say it has proved by far more valuable in my hands in the treatment of pneumonia, and other kindred diseases than any of the before named drugs, and, if I am deprived of aconite, the next drug with me is digitalis, then ergot. I consider both far superior to Norwood's veratrum in this southern country.

Here we have the "that X of a Y" form expressed not by a fictional character speaking dialect English, but a doctor writing a formal letter to a respected scientific publication. The reason he does so, I suspect, is that the wording "not much of a" was already established (on both sides of the Atlantic). For instance, in a [speech at the Whig convention](https://books.google.com/books?id=50o4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA285&dq=%22not+much+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=56vZVPOdH863oQTQ1oGwDw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22not%20much%20of%20a%22&f=false) of October 3, 1844, in Valley Forge Pennsylvania, Danial Webster has this assessment of the eight U.S. President, Martin Van Buren:

> Mr. Van Buren was **not much of a** tariff man, nor much of an 'anti-tariff man; he was **not much of a** proslavery man, nor much of an antislavery man, nor much of a decided man in any thing or on any question. He was not much for Texas, and he was not much against Texas.

And meanwhile in the English [*Sporting Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4XVBAQAAMAAJ&q=%22not+much+of+a%22&dq=%22not+much+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2K3ZVJLKKcb3oATg5oG4CQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjgK) (1850), this conversation is recorded:

> "How well your horse jumped that gate into the Leicester road, C.!" said L.; "I would. not have ridden at it for fifty pounds." Oh, yes, you would, my dear fellow ; it was **not much of a** gate, the taking off was so sound. But he really is a very good horse, I have no hunted him ten seasons, and he has certainly not given me ten falls."

As these predecessor phrases suggest, Dr. Waters's addition of *that* to the existing and established phrase "not much of a" yielded the form "not that much of a"; the *that*, not the *of*, is the odd word out. But as "not that much of a" and "that much of a" (without the *not*) became commonplace, they also provided a model for other phrases in which *good* or *big* or some other word replaced *much*—even though, in those cases, the syntactically odd element is the *of*, not the *this* or *that*. This chronology, I think, explains the emergence of "this good of a Y," "that big of a Y," and similar expressions in U.S. spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

As [this forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=670971) points out, "*so good a [something]*" (of which "*so good **of** a [something]*" is likely a more conversational variant) has been around long enough to be idiomatic in American English.

Expressions such as "*this good a wave*," "*so good a surfer*," and "*so great a love*" are all of a kind.

The same forum notes that Samuel Johnson used a similar construction, "So advantageous a principle," in his [second Rambler essay of 1801](http://www.openlibrary.org/details/therambler01johniala). The use of this construction in the English language no doubt predates Johnson's essay.

Comment: "*this good a wave," "so good a surfer," "so great a love"* are all clear to me and very commonly used in Britain.  The strangeness for me is precisely the additional word '*of*' -  *this good OF a wave," "so good OF a surfer," "so great OF a love"*.  At best, this sounds retro (hence my Mayflower query). @DaveP notwithstanding, I do not think this is word pattern is used, even 'conversationally' in Britain (except perhaps as an American import). Incidentally, I'm from Manchester and my partner is from around Liverpool - quite North !

Comment: As I noted in my answer, "so good _of_ a" is likely a _conversational_ variant. (I might have posited _regional_ as well, but Mark Foo was from Hawaii. I'm from Los Angeles, and I do hear that usage now and then.) If you Google [_so good of a_](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=intext:%22so+good+of+a%22), its use is more common than you might suspect.